# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't ignore disabled warnings

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2013, warnings

Good morning all. So I'm attempting to disable Warning 4996 in our c++ projects. It seems to be included in the command line as shown below, but upon compiling, still pops up with the C4966 Warning. I've tried changing the warning level to 3, or using /w44996, but neither have worked. Does anyone know why this might be?

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS- /W4 /wd"4100" /wd"4121" /wd"4201" /wd"4214" /wd"4244" /wd"4996" /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\..\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\..\Common Files\Designer" /I"D:\Workspaces\MST_Sustaining_Second\Inc" /I"D:\Workspaces\MST_Sustaining_Second\Develop\Shared\Include" /Zi /Gm /Od /Fd"D:\Workspaces\MST_Sustaining_Second\Develop\IDE\GrACE\Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_USRDLL" /D "ACE_DLL" /D "IQEDITOR_ENABLED" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "NTDDI_VERSION=NTDDI_WIN7" /D "_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601" /D "WINVER=0x0601" /D "_AFXDLL" /D "WIN32" /D "_SECURE_SCL=0" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /GF- /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oi /MDd /Fa"D:\Workspaces\MST_Sustaining_Second\Develop\IDE\GrACE\Debug\" /EHs /nologo /Fo"D:\Workspaces\MST_Sustaining_Second\Develop\IDE\GrACE\Debug\" /Fp"D:\Workspaces\MST_Sustaining_Second\Develop\IDE\GrACE\Debug\ace.pch"
```

EDIT: Typo in description. I do mean Warning 4996, not 4966. 4996 is in the command line as /wd"4996"

For Warning:

```
warning C4996: 'MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC': MBCS support in MFC is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of MFC.
```

Answer (score 15):

It looks like `#pragma warning(disable: 4996)` will not disable the MBCS deprecation warning due to the
`#pragma warning(1: 4996)` before the `_declspec(deprecated)` line in afx.h

For obscure reasons, you must use `#define NO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION` to disable this instead.

see afx.h lines 28-33

```
#ifndef NO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION
#ifdef _MBCS
// Warn about MBCS support being deprecated: see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=279048 for more information.
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(1 : 4996)
inline __declspec(deprecated("MBCS support in MFC is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of MFC.")) void MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC() { }
```

Comment: Very useful actually! It means you won't be disabling any other 'deprecated' warnings as a by-product of trying to make your project compile in C++11

Comment: [navigable link to Pat Brenner's blog re: this issue](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=279048)

Answer (score 8):

In order to [Pat Brenner](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Pat+Brenner+MSFT) (Visual C++ Libraries Development Team) mentioned in his [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/08/mfc-support-for-mbcs-deprecated-in-visual-studio-2013/) ,

> we are deprecating MBCS support in MFC for Visual Studio 2013. This
>   keeps MFC more closely aligned with the Windows SDK itself, because
>   many of the newest controls and messages are Unicode only
>
> This warning can be eliminated by adding the
>   `NO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION` preprocessor definition to your project
>   build definitions.

**Then do this.**

Go to **Project Properties-> C\C++ ->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definition** and add `NO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue but it was on some functions from `io.h` and `string.h` such as these:

`source.cxx(713) : warning C4996: 'stricmp': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _stricmp. See online help for details.
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\string.h(215) : see declaration of 'stricmp'`

`source.cxx(2416) : warning C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for details.
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\string.h(207) : see declaration of 'strdup'`

`source.cxx(2249) : warning C4996: 'isatty': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _isatty. See online help for det
ails.`

Due to the need to have the exact same code run be built on other platforms, I had to find a solution without fiddling much in code as this occurred all over the project in a lot of files.

The solution was to add this compiler flag `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`. This can be done in one of two ways:

1. Passing `-D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE` if you are using the `cl` command directly
2. Or from `Visual Studio GUI` if you use it for the building process. Add `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE` in **Project Properties > C\C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definition**

Comment: For VS 2017 they are errors not warnings. This is the correct answer.