# How to Disable C4996 Warning in C++ VS 2013

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I have converted a C++ solution with multiple projects from VS2010 to VS2013.

For legacy reasons we are sticking with multibyte characters and not going to Unicode.

I am trying to disable the plethora of C4996: `MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC` warnings.

I have read the related questions on this here and have tried to disable the specific warning under the Property Pages->Config Properties->C/C++->Advanced.

If I enter C4996, then I get a Command-Line Error D8021 complaining the number is greater than 65,534.

If I drop the leading "C" and just enter "4996" then it compiles albeit with the wretched C4996 warnings.

I have tried adding a semicolon but to no effect.

This is what the property setting looks like: `4996;%(DisableSpecificWarnings)`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to disable the warning. I'd rather try to fix it.

Comment: I don't know the answer. But I don't suppose I could persuade you to format your question in a readable manner, rather than one long paragraph?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24244544/560648? From the "Related" sidebar.

Comment: OK I checked out the above link in which Giles says: "It looks like #pragma warning(disable: 4996) will not disable the MBCS deprecation warning due to the #pragma warning(1: 4996) before the _declspec(deprecated) line in afx.h

For obscure reasons, you must use #define NO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION to disable this instead.

see afx.h lines 28-33" So where do I stick that #define?

Comment: BTW how do you add a new para in these comment boxes? Every time I hit Enter it posts the comment instead.

Comment: @DaveO'Connor: Comments are supposed to be short, not used for ongoing discussion and therefore you **intentionally** can't write paragraphs. That said, add the `#define` to every .cpp file, after `stdafx.h` but before you include the MFC headers that give you the problem. Nasty, but that's intentional too. It should be clear in every file that you're running an unsupported config. (If you have MFC headers in stdafx.h it might even be necessary to stuff the #define there)

Comment: @MSalters thanks. This is a big codebase and it looks like it's going to be a PITA